# File loader doesn't seem to work with a tag

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Webpack currently copies my images into my dist folder and hashes and injects them into the html. I've a sprite sheet for my svgs and I'd like to do the same.

Problem is that the file loader doesn't seem to work with a  tag, or the href attribute (which is why I've a similar problem with my favicon).

What's the best way to deal with this? I'm pretty new to webpack, so apologies if the answer is obvious, I've not been able to find it myself

Here's my config file (if it helps),

Thanks

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: ['html-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*** edit:

I've now tried using `svg-sprite-loader` in extract mode:

config:

```
    {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
            options: {
              extract: true,
              publicPath: '/static/'
            }
        }
    }
```

and using the plugin as the example docs show

`const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');`

```
plugins: [
    new SpriteLoaderPlugin()
]
```

but still no luck

Comment: File loader probably can't achieve what you want it to do: instead, you should be using a custom loader that is specifically made to handle SVG sprites, e.g. https://github.com/monoguerin/vue-svg-sprite-loader

Comment: yeah I did see svg-sprite-loader, but it seemed to create sprite sheets. turns out I didn't look at it hard enough and it has an 'extract' mode, which seems to be what I want. although it def seems above my ability right now!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so hopefully my limited understanding might help someone else.

I was assuming that the svg-sprite-loader would come across the svg in the html file, much as the file-loader does with images. But of course because the svg is linked in the href attribute it wasn't.

Basically I should've added `import '../assets/icons.svg';` to my app.js file

which now works, and I'll just hash the entire file (which i think may be my only option unless I can extract them one by one)